# Google cloudstorage api for setting x-y bytes of a file

Tags: android, git, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

i want to upload only the delta of a file in google cloud storage(gcs=google cloud storage). as gcs only allows to get a crc32 hash of the entire file but not the some part of the file (x - y bytes) i'm building local version indexes like git(but a poor version). now i just want to upload the delta of the file, for which i need gcs api methods to insert k bytes at nth location. and delete x-y bytes, modify x-y bytes.

i have searched but couldn't find anything about it. and i skirmed through "gsutil rsync" code and came to the conclusion that it is copying the entire file even if there is a small change in the file(please correct me if it is not the case.)

ps: if there are no such methods i will try to save 256KB blocks of each file. (my file sizes are in the range of 1MB-50MB)

pps: actually i want to upload only the delta of some binary files that i'm storing from android app. if you know any known tool or workflow for this please do answer.